# Storing query criteria in database

Tags: mysql, database

Let's imagine, that I have a table "greetings" that contains ~50K records like:

```
id  text
10  John Doe, You're dang lucky to get that far! Happy birthday!
```

And this record can be fetched using the following criteria (input variables are: name, birthday, today):

```
IF name == "John Doe" AND is_birthday(today, birthday) == true AND age(birthday) >= 95
```

Each record must satisfy from 1 to 4 conditions to get fetched.

What is the best practice to implement such logic?

Thanks.

Comment: use dynaminc query

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal, thank you, but it's a bit more complex than this. I need to assign different conditions to different records, and the number of conditions is not fixed. The variables arn't always the same (name and birthday), it might be weight, hair color etc. Different variables for different records.